# How to change header dimensions in Wordpress?

Tags: css, headers

How can I alter the requirements for the header dimensions so that I can take an uncropped image and fill the top section (centring the whole image) instead of having white space at the top? I would prefer to just be able to edit the CSS and not bother with child themes, as I don't think I will ever need to upgrade the theme.

Here is my site http://carolbadre.wordpress.com/

and here is the uncropped image:
http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/11-245/grr.png

Comment: WordPress.com probably won't allow you to edit the html of your theme http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/editing-themes/ - or check directly with http://en.forums.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

Put that code (this is the output):

```
<a href="http://carolbadre.wordpress.com/">
<img width="1000" alt="" src="http://carolbadre.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/cropped-grr.jpg">
</a>
```

Which must look different in the backend **inside a div**...
Then you can css it and use height: auto..